# Blocking ICMP outgoing requests only in eth1

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, nat

I am creating a NAT with iptables:

Computer A: eth0 (dhcp) + eth1 (static ip 192.168.0.1 - gateway)
Computer B: eth1 (static ip 192.168.0.2, using Computer A as gateway)

I know how to block ICMP outgoing requests (*-A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP*), but that would block ICMP requests from Computer A, but not from Computer B (in fact, only for Computer A - Computer B can keep doing those).

I tried with the same command, but adding -o *eth1*, but that does not block at all. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to the FORWARD table. (`-A FORWARD`).

- `INPUT` is for packets coming to the host (packets where the host is the destination, so in your case, packets destined for host A)
- `OUTPUT` is for packets going out of the host (originating on host A, going somewhere else)
- `FORWARD` is for packets forwarded for some other host (B in your case), to another host (whatever you are pinging, somewhere in the internet). Since those packets are just forwarded for someone else, `FORWARD` table is used here.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, I was missing that. Thank you! Just in case, this is the final result for anyone who wants it: *-A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP*